# Login problems after changing default port ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, port

I changed the Port in sshd_config file and restart the service (Using Linux Debian 8).
Logged out from SSH (Putty) and I tried to login later but I can't connect through Putty anymore.. I tried to login by FTP with FileZilla and that still works..

What is the problem?

Comment: You forgot: to open the port in the firewall and/or your password and to test things before things like this happen + FTP's port has nothing to do with SSH's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume `iptables` are not running and blocking it. It could be SE Linux. Try running:

```
sestatus
```

If it is enabled, then run:

```
semanage port -l | grep ssh
```

And if the output says `tcp 22`

then run the following to add the new port (e.g. 2222)

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2222
```

then finally run

```
semanage port -l | grep ssh
```

which should then show `22` and `2222`

and then it should work. If not then look into `iptables`:

```
iptables -nvL
```

will give you a list of what you have

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```

would add a rule allowing traffic into port `2222`, but this may not help depending on what other rules are present.

If `iptables` doesn't fix it then it could be a firewall between you and the server.

Comment: He does not have access to the server, executing commands on it it's going to be hard

Comment: he might have console access. I am hoping he does and helping on that basis. If not, then when he speaks to his provider and somehow gets the access back, then my answer should be useful if he wants to try again.

Comment: Most Debian users never enable SELinux.